# mongoDB database url environment variable not found

Tags: javascript, mongodb, .env

i am trying to connect to mongoDB server.

the error:

```
npx prisma db push
Environment variables loaded from .env
Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma
Datasource "db": MongoDB database
```

```
Error: Prisma schema validation - (get-config wasm)
Error code: P1012
error: Environment variable not found: DATABASE_URL.
  -->  schema.prisma:10
   | 
 9 |   provider = "mongodb"
10 |   url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
   | 

Validation Error Count: 1
[Context: getConfig]

Prisma CLI Version : 5.2.0
```

**.env file**

```
DATABASE_URL="mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.abcdefg.mongodb.net/test"
NEXTAUTH_JWT_SECRET=
NEXTAUTH_SECRET=
```

**schema.prisma file**

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}
```

I've tried

- creating new user names and passwords for mongoDB.
- added my current IP address and the 0.0.0.0/0
- double checking that the url is correct (copied from mongoDB).
- double checking that the package.json matches the tutorial i am following.